# Ajuda com instalação do php 7.0 no ubuntu conforme vídeo tutorial

Tags: mysql, laravel, nginx, php-7, mint

Seguindo esse vídeo tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=onVSVC_C1GE&t=717s. Ja no começo na alteração do default, feitas as alterações no default, o nginx index padrão deveria ser "subscrito" por o index.php configurado mais por algum motivo nada muda mesmo após as configurações sugeridas no vídeo alguém tem alguma sugestão? Não estou conseguindo realizar as configurações corretamente. E já formatei a  maquina para zerar as configurações, pois da ultima vez de tanto tentar nem o localhost estava carregando nos navegadores. Utilizo distribuição mint 18.3
O conteúdo do meu default segue nesse link único jeito que consegui colar o código da maneira que tá sem quebrar.
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/rafaumeu/333ba4ad4757566fe517d25a40871c2f/raw/855c0328d2a5f376c2b6df50ad8d6bc6a1f65141/gistfile1.txt

unica coisa que eu alterei no php.ini foi a linha onde estava escrito 
cgi.fix_pathinfo=0, que estava comentada e com valor igual a 1 e eu retirei o comentário e coloquei zero conforme os tutoriais que segui para que funcione corretamento com o php7.0-fpm.

Comment: Se você quiser carregar o *index.php* precisa alterar a configuração do *Nginx*. Normalmente essa configuração fica em `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`. Após alterações, basta reiniciar o servidor *Nginx* com o `sudo nginx -s reload`

Comment: @ValdeirPsr  foi feito eu fiz um teste criando um arquivo nomeado phpinfo.php e as informações são exibidas corretamente na url localhost/phpinfo.php porem no index onde chamo phpinfo(); ao digitar localhost eu esperava q o index padrão nginx fosse substituído  por informações do php, o q ñ ocorreu continua a exibir o index padrão

Comment: Se possível clica em [edit] e posta o código do arquivo de configuração do Nginx.

Comment: @ValdeirPsr farei isso a noite vc fala o default ñ é?

Comment: Se possível poste o arquivo de configuração refente ao seu site. Pode ser o *default* ou outro.

Comment: Vo editar a pergunta e add o default

Answer (score 1):

Eu não entendi bem aonde você falhou, mas primeiro, para editar o `php.ini` no Nginx (lembre-se este no Ubuntu usa FPM) edite este arquivo (independente do editor de texto):

- `/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini`

É **obrigatório** usar `sudo` ou `su`

Se você adicionou alguma extensão ou editou algo no php.ini é necessário reiniciar o FPM, pois se não isto não terá efeito, assim:

```
sudo systemctl restart php7.0-fpm
```

Comment: Foi reiniciado só q mesmo assim não rodou estou meio perdido se for o caso posto o conteúdo de arquivos que foram alterados até então assim q chegar do serviço faco isso

Comment: @RafaelDiasZendron o que exatamente deveria ter mudado?

Comment: @RafaelDiasZendron esquece o video, o que exatamente você quer liberar? Seria o SSL ?

Comment: O laravel deveria carregar automaticamente do diretório /var/www/html mas isso vai ser feito posteriormente. O diretório /var/www/html atualmente tem o index padrão do nginx  e um index.php q deveria "subscrever" o index padrão do nginx por phpinfo(); mas n funcionou

Comment: @RafaelDiasZendron o arquivo index.php esta marcado como escrita e leitura nas permissões de pasta? Alterou as permissões da pasta?

Comment: preciso ver isso vc fala dar um chmod 777?

Comment: @RafaelDiasZendron não precisa ser 777 (isso é até meio que exagerado), vamos esquecer isto de permissão, me diz como esta a sua configuração do Nginx? Tem como mandar?

Comment: Vou mandar sim a noite vc fala o defaul não é?

Comment: @RafaelDiasZendron isso mesmo, o `default`

Comment: Vo editar a pergunta e add o default

Comment: Eu encontrei o erro e era um negócio bem bombo kkk